# how to position text so that it won't move along background image?

Tags: html, css

My site is responsive.I want to make the text placed in a div not to move along the background image.

**css**

```
#target {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('../img/top-bg.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;
     width: 120%; height: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    background-size:cover;
}
#target.wide{
    left: -20%;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12  columns home" style="background-color:#ff0;width: 100%; height: 400px; float: left; z-index:2000; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="target">
        <div class="small-12 medium-11 large-11 columns text2">
                 Beyond Law,<br/>
                 The Spirit of Innovation is Our strenght.
                 </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compensate `20%` offset by setting opposite `padding-left` for `wide` class:

```css
#target.wide {
    left: -20%;
    padding-left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: thanks...it helps but i don't understand why the text flies to the top.Is it possible to move it from top to bottom instead? Here's the link:http://vani.valse.com.my/beldon/index.php#

Comment: Because you add `wide` class dynamically with javascript so it is being transitioned according to CSS rules. You can remove `transition: all 2s ease-in-out;` if you don't want this behavior.